# How to find a the target level a annotation is applied to in javax custom validator

Tags: java, spring, validation, hibernate-validator

Am implementing a custom validator for a service call. As part of it i have a below annotation.

```
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {MyAnnotationValidator.class})
public @interface MyAnnotation {

}
```

I can apply the above annotation to element type of field or parameter. Invoking the annotation at either parameter or field would end up in my constraint validator class.

Validation logic is same for both the element types. But incase of validation failure i need to send different message for both the elements.

In case of a parameter validation failure i need to say "parameter validation failed", in other case i need to say "Field validation failed".

Is there is any way i can know from which element type does the validation call has reached to validator.

Solution i have is send a Custom attribute with the annotation to indicate from where it is called. Some thing like this.

```
@MyAnnotation("Parameter") or @MyAnnotation("Field").
```

Need to know if there is an efficient way to perform this operation. Please let me know if more information is required.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm you that there is no good way to do that right now.

Wondering if we should expose something in `HibernateConstraintValidatorContext`. I'll think about it.

Comment: Yeah it would be helpful if the validatorcontext can expose a method to fetch this info.